# Getting length of array with attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have this array with attributes and i want to get its' length. In this case the array length should be 2 since there are only 2 "items"

```
 {"items":[{"value":"2","valor":0,"name":"Limpeza"},
 {"value":"6","valor":0,"name":"TECREMOVE"}]}
```

I've already tried `exist.length` but it returns `undefined`. How can i get its' length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myObj = {"items":[{"value":"2","valor":0,"name":"Limpeza"},
    {"value":"6","valor":0,"name":"TECREMOVE"}]};

var arrLength = myObj.items.length;
```

`myObj.items` - is the array, `myObj.items.length` - length of that array.

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you.(i'll accept the answer as soon as possible)

Answer (score 1):

You're having an **`object`** which one of it's properties with the name **`items`** is an `array` with the length of 2.

Try:

```
var data =  {"items":[{"value":"2","valor":0,"name":"Limpeza"},
 {"value":"6","valor":0,"name":"TECREMOVE"}]};

var len = data.items.length;
```